# Can't see the label nodes in Neo4j Web Client after store upgrade

Tags: neo4j

I have small problem with setting up my Neo4j. More precisely my problem concerns Sample DataSets which i found here:

http://neo4j.com/developer/example-data/

I downloaded it (Jim Webber’s Doctor Who Data Set ), extracted in to database catalog, and started Neo4j.
I got an error message, so I set `allow_store_upgrade=true` in a config file.

Neo4j started, but unfortunately I can't see any Node Labels in a web client app.

[image: no node labels]

I'm sure that there should be labels like Character or Species.

I can add my own labels nnd I can see them then.

```
match (n {character:'Doctor'})
set n :myTestLabel
return n
```

Are the original labels lost after `allow_store_upgrade=true`?

I'm using Neo4j 2.1.7 on Windows 8.1

If you have any ideas how to solve this issue, please let me know!

Thanks!

Mike

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It could be that the original data was for Neo4j 1.9 and didn't yet contain labels. I'll check and update the dataset if necessary.

You can list the existing labels by running

```
MATCH (n) 
RETURN labels(n), count(*)
```

Comment: Hey Michael, the dataset is indeed for 1.9, however the neo4j-tutorial repo on jim's github account has been updated to 2.1. I've build the koans and will try to backup the db from there.

Comment: I was watching "Introduction to Graph Databases and Neo4j" course on pluralsight.
Roland downloaded Dataset (Jim Webber’s Doctor Who Data Set ) which already had node labels. So I assumed that they should be there. I thought that there are some problems with store upgrade but it is probably not the case.
Thank you for the answer!

Comment: Hi Guys, how do you solve this? I dont see labels as well

Answer (score 3):

Let me rephrase your question:  "I am taking the pluralsight course 'Introduction to Graph Databases and Neo4j', I downloaded the DrWho database from GitHub, and I had to configure `allow_store_upgrade=true` in order to start the database. But after starting it, I did not see any labels, even though in the course video there are labels. How do I get the labels?"

Answer to that question: The course instructor admits in the discussion forum (https://app.pluralsight.com/library/courses/graph-databases-neo4j-introduction/discussion) that the database on GitHub does not have labels, and the database which he used in the course was actually a modified version of it. That modified version is in the course's Exercise Files zip download. If you download that modified version of the db (and run allow_store_upgrade=true), you'll see the labels.

Comment: when I downloaded the modified version in the exercise files, I am not able to start the server, can you please help?

Answer (score 0):

Try with the 2.3.9 version first and set allow_store_upgrade=true. It should work